# Could humans cause an earthquake?

Tags: earthquakes

I saw something that mentioned how, during the 2018 World Cup, after a victory, thousand of fans jumping simultaneously caused seismologists to detect the equivalent energy release of a magnitude 2.0 earthquake. They then rhetorically posited the question, "What if the entire global population gathered in one place and did the same thing?", but gave no answer. Therefore, I am wondering, is it possible to calculate, and if so what would be, the equivalent seismic magnitude of 8 billion people jumping?

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/8/

Comment: @John - That is an interesting and entertaining read but it doesn't answer my question. That focuses on the logistical problem of 8 billion people leaving Rhode Island and not the maths of the seismic energy release.

Comment: ...aaand just scaling up the number of people with the energy of a mag 2 earthquake doesn't work for this, as upper estimate?

Comment: @Ethan but the two sources in the beginning cover it in breathtaking detail. https://scienceblogs.com/dotphysics/2010/08/26/what-if-everyone-jumped and https://www.straightdope.com/21341323/if-everyone-in-china-jumped-off-chairs-at-once-would-the-earth-be-thrown-out-of-its-orbit